# .htaccess doesn't take effect on my Ubuntu droplet but does its job right on my personal PC. Am I forgetting to change some Apache setting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this `.htaccess` file for my Vue.js project which allows my Vue.js to use the history routing mode. Unfortunately, the `.htacess` doesn't take effect when I put it in my Vue.js project folder that is located on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet. I know there's nothing wrong with the `.htacess` file because it does what it is supposed to do on my personal PC.

Is there some sort of Apache setting I need to turn on first, which I'm forgetting about? The file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A86400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
#
<FilesMatch "\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦ico¦css¦js¦swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Usually this is due to a missing `AllowOverride` in the server/virtualhost config. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: Also, remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper, in case mod_rewrite is not enabled. (You should only use the `<IfModule>` wrapper if you are installing the same code on multiple servers where mod_rewrite might not be available and it is an _optional_ component. By the sounds of it, it's not optional. See [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary) on the Webmasters stack for more info.)